# Do bokey DateSlider values change their format from date to datetime on the webpage?

Tags: python, bokeh

I used one of the [examples](https://pypkg.com/pypi/bokeh/f/examples/models/file/sliders.py) on Python Package Documentation webside to add a DateSlider widget to my bokeh webapplication. My goal is to create a DateSlider with start date October, 10th 2017, end date October, 16th 2017 and step equal one day. On change of the DateSlider value I expect to get the new value (in date format) printed in the windows shell. Instead I get the OSError 22.

I run the following script on the windows shell with command "bokeh serve try_dateslider.py --show":

```
from bokeh.models.widgets import DateSlider
from bokeh.plotting import curdoc
from datetime import date

def callback(attrname, old, new):
    print ("yeeeah", slider.value)

slider = DateSlider(start=date(2017, 10, 10), end=date(2017, 10, 17),
                    value=date(2017, 10, 17), step=1, title="Stuff")
slider.on_change('value', callback)

curdoc().add_root(slider)
```

The widget is displayed in the [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZcQ22.png) as expected. However, when I move the slider I get the OSError 22 in windows shell. Here is the full output from the shell:

```
PS C:\Users\bokeh_graphs> bokeh serve try_dateslider.py --show
2017-10-24 09:07:01,624 Starting Bokeh server version 0.12.9 (running on Tornado 4.5.2)
2017-10-24 09:07:01,629 Bokeh app running at: http://localhost:5006/try_dateslider
2017-10-24 09:07:01,629 Starting Bokeh server with process id: 13764
2017-10-24 09:07:02,033 200 GET /try_dateslider (::1) 291.20ms
2017-10-24 09:07:02,358 101 GET /try_dateslider/ws?bokeh-protocol-version=1.0&
bokeh-session-id=pj6DRIQHoty4sWtH5fFHRvvWEsAutoUeTHpuPXaWvDyj (::1) 1.00ms
2017-10-24 09:07:02,358 WebSocket connection opened
2017-10-24 09:07:02,361 ServerConnection created
2017-10-24 09:07:08,478 error handling message Message 'PATCH-DOC' (revision 1): 
OSError(22, 'Invalid argument')
```

I have also tried to create the same DateSlider widget using a CustomJS callback, which allows to specify the callback policy and the format of the DateSlider values in the webapplication. This time I do not expect the new value to be printed in the shell on change of DateSlider value. Again I use the "bokeh serve try_dateslider.py --show" command on the windows shell to run the following script:

```
from bokeh.models.widgets import DateSlider
from bokeh.plotting import curdoc
from datetime import date
from bokeh.models import CustomJS

callback = CustomJS(code="""
var rel_date = slider.value;
""")

slider = DateSlider(title='Date of Calculation:', value=date(2017, 10, 17),
                    start=date(2017, 10, 10), end=date(2017, 10, 17), step=1,
                    callback_policy='mouseup', format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
rel_date = slider.value
slider.js_on_change('value', callback)

# Print the relevant date to check what value the 'slider.value' returns. I do not expect
# to get the rel_date value printed in callback anymore
print ("the relevant date is ", rel_date)

curdoc().add_root(slider)
```

The widget is displayed in the [output #2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MoZrA.png) as expected. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EmjC2.png) is an example of how the output looks like when the slider has been moved. The step=1 in DateSlider widget definition does not seem to equal one day. And in windows shell I get the same error message as earlier. Here is the full output from the windows shell:

```
PS C:\Users\bokeh_graphs> bokeh serve try_dateslider.py --show
2017-10-24 09:31:48,033 Starting Bokeh server version 0.12.9 (running on Tornado 4.5.2)
2017-10-24 09:31:48,037 Bokeh app running at: http://localhost:5006/try_dateslider
2017-10-24 09:31:48,037 Starting Bokeh server with process id: 11600
the relevant date is  2017-10-17
2017-10-24 09:31:48,465 200 GET /try_dateslider (::1) 316.47ms
2017-10-24 09:31:48,880 101 GET /try_dateslider/ws?bokeh-protocol-
version=1.0&bokeh-session-id=8XFPdCZRCoDvOFZUVGwvP5TnLpKOvouNrOAlRUHux7Ar (::1) 1.02ms
2017-10-24 09:31:48,880 WebSocket connection opened
2017-10-24 09:31:48,883 ServerConnection created
2017-10-24 09:38:28,572 error handling message Message 'PATCH-DOC' (revision 1): 
OSError(22, 'Invalid argument')
```

I am using Python 3.6.3 (64bit) and bokeh 0.12.9. The following might be related but did not solve my problem:

[Bokeh Plot Update Using Slider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43579881/bokeh-plot-update-using-slider)

[Bokeh - DateSlider still broken?](https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/#!topic/bokeh/WKoNVbnEh3s)